# nuxt3 packages mismatch at build stage

Tags: firebase, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I know Nuxt3 is in release candidate, but it has been announced as almost stable so I am trying to deploy my SSR app on firebase hosting, using a cloud function.

To do so, and because I am new to the Nuxt and the Firebase environment, I am following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@sirofjelly/deploying-a-nuxt-ssr-server-side-rendering-app-to-google-firebase-5d90117167db.

Here is my **package.json**:

```json
 {
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "firebase:start:import_export": "firebase emulators:start --import=./test/ --export-on-exit=./exported_datas/",
    "firebase:export": "firebase emulators:export ./test/",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions && firebase deploy --only hosting",
    "clean": "rm -rf .nuxt .output dist node_modules *.log",
    "clean_all": "npm run clean && rm -rf functions/node_modules functions/nuxt"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n": "^0.5.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.33.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.33.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
    "eslint": "^8.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.3.0",
    "nuxt": "^3.0.0-rc.11",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/vue": "^1.6.7",
    "@heroicons/vue": "^2.0.10",
    "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^7.3.0",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.7.0",
    "bulma": "^0.9.4",
    "bulma-carousel": "^4.0.24",
    "firebase": "^9.9.3",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.23.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^11.8.0",
    "nuxt-start": "^2.15.8",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  }
}
```

Here is my **firebase.json** file:

```json
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "./firebase_rules/database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "predeploy": [
      "rm -rf public/* && mkdir -p public/_nuxt && cp -r .nuxt/dist/client/ public/_nuxt && cp -a static/. public/"
    ],
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
     "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "ssrapp"
      }
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "./firebase_rules/storage.rules"
  },
  "functions": {
    "runtime": "nodejs16",
    "source": "functions",
    "predeploy": [
      "npm run build && rm -rf functions/nuxt && cp -r .nuxt/ functions/nuxt/ && cp nuxt.config.ts functions/"
    ]
  },
  "emulators": {
    "hosting": {
      "port": 3001
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "database": {
      "port": 9000
    },
    "storage": {
      "port": 9199
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001,
      "host": "localhost"
    },
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    }
  }
}
```

**The observed behavior**:
When I run the build command `npm run build`, everything goes well, the build works fine.
But when the predeploy command launch the same build command (see firebase.json in the functions config), the build raise a specific error:

```bash
Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: 

Vue packages version mismatch:

- vue@3.2.41
- vue-server-renderer@2.7.13
```

No solution from https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6823 worked on my problem

I tried a lot of things with packages but without success.
Have anybody an idea to solve the problem ? Is this a Nuxt3-rc12 issue ?

Thanks for help

Comment: The given article is quite old (2021) already. I recommend using this solution: https://nitro.unjs.io/deploy/providers/firebase

Comment: Unfortunately this tutorial seems to concern static deploying, I am working on a SSR app

Comment: Isn't `.output/server` for SSR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was presented at:  https://nitro.unjs.io/deploy/providers/firebase